# How to parse an id URL parameter express?

Tags: node.js, express

```
router.get('/matches/:id', checkJWT, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req.params ', req.params);
});
```

Even the request params are not printing in console log:

```
OPTIONS /api/accounts/matches?id=5d693ba93aae6a6caa6c3cda 204 2.213 ms - 0
GET /api/accounts/matches?id=5d693ba93aae6a6caa6c3cda 200 4.877 ms - 1362
OPTIONS /api/accounts/matches?id=5d693ba93aae6a6caa6c3cda 204 0.131 ms - 0
GET /api/accounts/matches?id=5d693ba93aae6a6caa6c3cda 304 1.497 ms
```

Strange. I am not able to understand whats the issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/matches/:id` is expecting request to come in as such

```
/api/accounts/matches/5d693ba93aae6a6caa6c3cda
```

If you want to use query params like `/api/accounts/matches?id=5d693ba93aae6a6caa6c3cda`, you gotta change your URL matching pattern to `/matches` and read the param from `req.query`. Check this out

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params

Comment: If you want to use `req.query`, your router path must be changed to `/matches` only (i.e. `router.get('/matches`, ...)`

Comment: it doesn't even print `req` object

Comment: yes your handler isn't executing because the URL is not matching with what u provided to the router, please refer to the previous comment

Comment: I am using `const userRoutes = require('./routes/account');
app.use('/api/accounts', userRoutes);`

Comment: dude let me just rewrite your code for you 
`router.get('/matches', checkJWT, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req.query ', req.query);
});`

Comment: Actually you are right. I shouldn't pass `/:id`. Your comment helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should work using req.query.id